# AWS inbound trafic is blocked after routing the outbound trafic from the subnets through NAT gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

What I am trying to achieve here is to simply have a static ip address for tasks running in my ecs services. I need this in order to be able to whitelist the ip address in the 3-d parties api.

What I did was: I created a new subnet, inside of this subnet I added a NAT gateway, then created new route table for this subnet that routes all of the trafic to the internet gateway

[image]

After that I updated the routing table that is used by existing subnets to route all trafic to the NAT gateway

[image]

It works great for the outbound trafic and updates the ip address of the request to the ip address of the Elastic IP associated with the NAT gateway.

But it also blocks all of the inbound trafic - canceling any request that try sending.
I am not sure why this is happening, the inbound request destination should fall into the local routing rule, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Load Balancer subnet - since I modified the existing subnets route table to route trafic to the nat gateway, I accidentaly also made load balancers subnet private, assigning them the new subnets fixed the issue